# Truffle - Solidity Mapping unable to access via JS

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, cpp-ethereum

Good day,

I am currently new in Solidity development, hope you can help me with this one.

I have this contract that states:

```
contract Shop {
  struct Item {
    string name;
    string description;
    address tAddress;
    uint256 price;
    bool isHidden;
  }

  address public owner;

  mapping(address => Item) public items;

  constructor() public {
    owner=msg.sender;

    items[owner].price = 0.00;
    items[owner].description = "";
    items[owner].name = "";
  }

  // Adding an item
  function addItem(uint256 price, string memory name, string memory description) public returns (Item memory) {
    items[owner].price = price;
    items[owner].description = description;
    items[owner].name = name;
    items[owner].tAddress = owner;
    items[owner].isHidden = true;

    return (items[owner]);
  }

  // Retrieving the items
  function getItem(address _key) public returns (Item memory) {
    Item memory item = items[owner];
    return item;
  }
}
```

I can get right return for addItem but upon the getItem method it seems like it wont respond to the right value.

I do get this return:

[image: getItem return]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the JS Code:

```
  state = { storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = Shop.networks[networkId];

      console.log(" deployedNetwork ");
      console.log(deployedNetwork);
      console.log(Shop);

      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        Shop.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  runExample = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
    const sender = await contract.methods.showSender.call();

    console.log(" sender ");
    console.log(sender);

    shopItems.map(async (item) => {
      const addedItem = await contract.methods.addItem(item.price, item.name, item.description).call();

      console.log(addedItem);
    })

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    console.log(" account ");
    console.log(accounts[0]);

    const response = await contract.methods.getItem(accounts[0]).call();

    console.log(" response ");
    console.log(response);
    // Update state with the result.
    // this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  };
```

Comment: Please, can you add your JS code?

Comment: @Kerry99 added the JS code, please see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use send instead of call for the variables to update inside the chain.